# SQL neatly self join a table n times

Tags: sql

I'm building a back-end for a project to construct a (purely functional) graph database system.

One operation I'm trying to implement is self joining a precomputed view to itself exactly n times (i.e. finding pairs of results that are exactly n instances of a particular relation away from each other in the graph)

A slightly ugly solution I've come up with is generating a big tree of joins in a style similar to [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)

Is there a neater/better way to do this? Perhaps using recursive queries?

Each possible pre-generated view has a left_id and right_id field, which represent indices into entity tables.

A simplified example is the following:

Given the following table representing part of the relation `n -> succ(n)` (in reality the relation may be much more complicated)

```
left_id | right_id
__________________
   1    |    2
   2    |    3
   3    |    4
   4    |    5
   5    |    6
   7    |    8
```

The ideal result of querying with n = 3 would be

```
left_id | right_id
__________________
   1    |    4
   2    |    5
   3    |    6
   4    |    7
   5    |    8
```

(An explanation of why I'm using SQL is that one part of this project is to demonstrate that SQL is a poor choice for such a system, followed by a more bespoke backend to solve the issues with using an underlying relational as opposed to a graph model)

Comment: Please add an example of what you try to do

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Given your example this would be as simple as `select * from the_table where right_id - left_id = 3`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Most likely PostgreSQL. The example is heavily simplified. In reality, the pre-generated table is likely to be the result of a complicated compound query, with arbitrary IDs for the values. I simply used `n -> succ(n)` as an example relation to make it clear what is initially related to what.

Comment: Well, you simplified your example to a point where you won't get usable answers.

Answer (score 0):

Many databases support recursive CTEs, which directly support such graph walking.

Even in databases that do not, this is not particularly difficult, using dynamic SQL and a `WHERE` clause:

For n = 1:

```
select t1.left_id, t2.right_id
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t2.left_id = t1.right_id;
```

For n = 2:

```
select t1.left_id, t3.right_id
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t2.left_id = t1.right_id join
     t t3
     on t3.left_id = t2.right_id;
```

For n = 3:

```
select t1.left_id, t4.right_id
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t2.left_id = t1.right_id join
     t t3
     on t3.left_id = t2.right_id join
     t t4
     on t4.left_id = t3.right_id;
```

Each additional value of "n" adds another `join` condition.  These queries can readily take advantage of an index on the table, so performance should be reasonable.

Whether this is better or worse than graph databases is somewhat moot.  Each type of database has different strengths.  Many relational databases do support recursive CTEs (and hence graph walking).  However, the performance is probably going to be better on a software system specifically designed for this purpose.

Comment: In my experience (Postgres, Oracle) the recursive queries are actually quite fast - at least if you are looking at a single "graph" (e.g. pick one root node, then follow that) but not so much if you need to look at "everything" e.g. get the count of children for every root node

Comment: Currently, I've got the equivalent of your more manual  second solution, except my code generating function looks more like:  (I'm not sure if this will format how I want it to) ```JoinN(query, 1) = query | JoinN(query, 2n + 1) = join(query, JoinN(join(query, query), n) | JoinN(query, 2n) = JoinN(join(query, query), n)``` where join(a, b) is short hand for renaming the subqueries a,b to fresh variables and joining on left_id = right_id

Comment: On the topic of recursive CTEs, I understand how to construct a CTE to find the union of nodes in the graph which are reachable in upto n steps of  a given relation. But I am not sure how construct one to give results reached by *exactly* n steps of the relation.